# user defined concatenation function

Tags: c

I'm learning C and I came across the below code which implements concatenation but I am struggling to understand the second portion despite recapping pointer/increment precedence and associativity.

I have run examples of all the different combinations of dereferencing and post/pre increment and now recall that pre-increment with dereferencing is right to left associative e.g ***++q** where the inc would occur first. The page I learned from stated that post-increment with the dereference operator has the increment as higher precedence and goes on to say that the associativity of this example is left to right. I don't particularly know why it mentions the associativity as I understand precedence is regarded before it e.g ***p++** would increment before its dereference.

The below code starts by recursively calling itself with a pre-inc on dest to get to the end of the destination string which is denoted by it reaching and dereferencing the null byte. At this point, I lose track because I would have thought it would simply the dereferenced dest to the dereferenced src however it post increments it which based off what I've learned would increment to the memory location after the null byte dereference it and proceed to assign the string "eeksfor" to the position above the null byte in dest. Not only does this confuse me but the program goes on to call itself in another ternary operator / return 0 for seemingly no reason.

Thanks

```
/* my_strcat(dest, src) copies data of src to dest.  To do so, it first           reaches end of the string dest using recursive calls my_strcat(++dest, src).         Once end of dest is reached, data is copied using  
(*dest++ = *src++)?  my_strcat(dest, src). */
void my_strcat(char *dest, char *src) 
{ 
  (*dest)? my_strcat(++dest, src): (*dest++ = *src++)? my_strcat(dest,   src): 0 ; 
} 

/* driver function to test above function */
int main() 
{ 
  char dest[100] = "geeksfor"; 
  char *src = "geeks"; 
  my_strcat(dest, src); 
  printf(" %s ", dest); 
  getchar(); 
}
```

I ran the program and it does what it is expected to do. That is it returns the string "geeksforgeeks" so clearly I'm just not understanding something

Comment: It may be helpful for you to take that one big expression and break it down into an equivalent series of statements and expressions that would be easier for you to understand.

Comment: Its really not that big of an expression and the main part I don't understand is the assignment of dest. Specifically the reason for its post-increment.

Comment: Actually, this statement in your question is wrong: "e.g *p++ would increment before its dereference." -- it's a post-increment, so the dereference happens using the original (non-incremented) value of p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you understand the first recursive bit fine (keep incrementing dst to find the end).

Once you've found the end, it's time to start copying. The code it's using to copy one byte is: (*dest++ = *src++)

It might help your understanding to expand that code to something like: *dest = *src; dest += 1; src += 1 
(because they are post-increment operators)

Now, a normal 'copy' function would repeat that statement in a *while* or *for* loop, but because we are cleverly showing off, we use a second ternary operator and recursion. The final '0' doesn't really do anything, but it needs to be there as the "else" part of the ternary operator.

While this may not be the worst implementation of *strcat* ever written, it's certainly a strong contender.

Comment: Thanks I get it now, I saw that __*p++__ gave the post-increment a higher precedence and thought that meant it would occur before dereferencing.